# How to use NSMutableDictionary to store and retrieve data

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, nsmutabledictionary

I have created Window Based application and tab bar controller as root controller. My objective is to store Text Field data values in one tab bar VC and will be accessible and editable by other VC and also retrievable when application start.

I am looking to use NSMutableDictionary class in AppDelegate so that I can access stored Data Values with keys.

```
//TestAppDelegate.h

extern NSString *kNamekey ;
extern NSString *kUserIDkey ;
extern NSString *kPasswordkey ;

@interface TestAppDelegate :NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate>{
 UIWindow *window;
 IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;
 NSMutableDictionary *outlineData ;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *outlineData ;
@end

//TestAppDelegate.m
 #import "TestAppDelegate.h"

NSString *kNamekey =@"Namekey";
NSString *kUserIDkey =@"UserIDkey";
NSString *kPasswordkey =@"Passwordkey";

@implemetation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize outlineData ;

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication)application
{


  NSMutableDictionary *tempMutableCopy = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kRestoreLocationKey] mutableCopy];
 self.outlineData = tempMutableCopy;
 [tempMutableCopy release];
 if(outlineData == nil){
 NSString *NameDefault   = NULL;
 NSString *UserIDdefault= NULL;
 NSString *Passworddefault= NULL;


 NSMutableDictionary *appDefaults = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      NameDefault, kNamekey ,
      UserIDdefault, kUserIDkey ,      
      Passworddefault, kPasswordkey ,      
      nil];
 self.outlineData = appDefaults;
  [appDefaults release];
  }

 [window addSubview:rootController.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];

 NSMutableDictionary *savedLocationDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:outlineData forKey:kRestoreLocationKey];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:savedLocationDict];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:outlineData forKey:kRestoreLocationKey];
}
@end
Here ViewController is ViewController of Navigation Controller which is attached with one tab bar.. I have attached xib file with ViewController

//ViewController.h
@interface
   IBOutlet UITextField *Name;
   IBOutlet UITextField *UserId;
   IBOutlet UITextField *Password;
}
@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Name
@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserId;
@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Password;
-(IBAction)Save:(id)sender;
@end

Here in ViewController.m, I am storing object values with keys.
/ViewController.m
-(IBAction)Save:(id)sender{

  TestAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TestAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [appDelegate.outlineData setObject:Name.text forKey:kNamekey ];
   [appDelegate.outlineData setObject:UserId.text forKey:kUserIDkey ];
   [appDelegate.outlineData setObject:Password.text forKey:kPasswordkey];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];   
}

I am accessing stored object using following method.
-(void)loadData
{

 TabBarAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TabBarAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 Name = [appDelegate.outlineData  objectForKey:kNamekey ];
 UserId = [appDelegate.outlineData  objectForKey:kUserIDkey ];
 Password = [appDelegate.outlineData  objectForKey:kPasswordkey];


 [Name release];
 [UserId release]; 
 [Password release];

}
```

I am getting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in application. Where I am making mistake ?
Thanks,

Comment: it helps to use the debugger to check where the exception is occurring in your code, or if it is an overrelease problem.

Comment: I am also debugging step by step but some times application gives error when try to access values and sometimes it give when Trying enter TextField Data.-Thanks

Comment: I have deleted all Preference from iPhoneSimulator folder and When start application then it creating preference and storing keys in -save action and first time retrieving value in load data then after when I tried to entered data in Textfield that time Application gave EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
Then I have checked Preference .plist file in that it was not showing any entry of data.
Before deleting  prefernece files from iphoneSimulator folder, it was showing entries. 
Thanks

Comment: You should post a different question for that.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating objects as autoreleased, and then calling release on them (eg in loadData).  You need to read the Memory Management Guide.  You should only be calling release on objects that you have created using alloc or copy.

Comment: Here, Name, UserID and Password are declared in another tab bar interface viewController as NSString and property declared as @property(copy,nonatomic)NSString *Name;

I want to use this all objects in another method.
Does it require to release it or not?
The way I am making NSMutableDictionary is correct method ?

thanks,

Comment: Within your (edited) code snippet above, outlineData seems to be used correctly.

You really need to read that memory management guide.  Objects that retain (or alloc or copy) other objects are responsible for releasing them.

Comment: Hello Paull, Thanks. I will check all objects release part

Thanks,